# Random value excluding both limits

Tags: javascript, random

The javascript method `Math.random()` returns a (pseudo-)random float between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

In some use cases, I need both limits to be excluded, a random float between 0 (**exclusive**) and 1 (exclusive).

This is what I currently use to generate said random float:

```
do {
    var random = Math.random();
} while(random === 0);
```

But I have a feeling that the (possibly) multiple draws from the random pool somehow mess up the distribution of my random floats.

**Is there any downside to using this snippet and if so, how could I generate random floats while excluding both the lower and the upper limits?**

Comment: This is not a code review question as it does not contain real-world working code but rather hypothetical code. I belive this question to be off-topic for this site.

Comment: @EmilyL.: I disagree. The three lines shown above are real-world working code, which I actually use to generate a float between 0 and 1 and about which I have doubts.

Comment: There is nothing to review. The question boils down to "Is this correct code or not?" as such it is better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: @EmilyL. I think that this is about a specific bit of code, the fact that it can help other people isn't something that we should discourage, I feel. The snippet of code is small, but that's not an issue, provided it's an MVCE. The solution that Lars has is a valid one, they are asking if there's a better one.

Comment: @Yann Code Review does not endorse MCVE's! That's SO style.

Comment: @janos: But the provided code works as intended, to the best of my knowledge. I *don't know* if using a loop has any unintended side-effects, that is what I am asking. By the way, the code snippet is not even intended to be an MCVE, I just copied it out of my source code.

Comment: @LarsEbert your question is really "Is this the correct way to generate a reasonably uniform distribution of random floats in the range `(0, 1)` (bounds excluded) ?" It's an interesting question, but it's not a code review question. Your question is not about the general quality of your code, but very specifically about one narrow area of generating uniformly distributed random numbers. Random numbers are extremely tricky, and I doubt you will find here the kind of authoritative answer you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Please do not use the approach given in @Yann's answer:

> `var random = Math.random() * (1 - Number.MIN_VALUE) + Number.MIN_VALUE;`

The reason is that `Number.MIN_VALUE == 5E-324`. As numbers in javascript are doubles with 52 bit mantissa and the largest number smaller than 1.0 that can be represented is somewhere around `1.0 - 2^(-52)`. The expression `(1 - 5e-324)`  is not representable and will truncate to exactly `1.0`.

The addition of `Number.MIN_VALUE` to the random value will also truncate for large parts of the number range, skewing your distribution.

The correct (and fastest) way to do this is by using the original code in OP's question (as also pointed out by @200_success's answer).

#### Addendum:

Even if we let: `almost_one` be the largest value smaller than 1.0 and then did:

```
var random = Math.random()*almost_one + Number.MIN_VALUE;
```

then the value would still be wrong.

To achieve a uniform distribution `Math.random()` must only return values with the same exponent (i.e. only the mantissa differs). Otherwise you'd have many more numbers between [0, 0.01]  than you would between [0.01, 1.0].

So for any return value of `Math.random()` besides `0.0` the addition of `Number.MIN_VALUE` will truncate. However if `Math.random()` returns 0.0 you will get the smallest value larger than 0.0 that is representable (5e-324) as your result. But then there will be a huge gap to the next number that you can get as a result, so your distribution will not be uniform any more.

The following is also wrong:

```
var random = Math.random()*almost_one + (1.0 - almost_one);
```

This can easily be seen by assuming that `Math.random()` returns its maximal value which is `almost_one`, then you would have:

```
var random = almost_one*almost_one + (1.0 - almost_one);
```

which is not equal to `almost_one` (it's close, but not correct).

Comment: I yield to your greater knowledge, I've deleted my answer to not confuse anyone further.

Answer (score 9):

This is a loop that almost always executes just once.  It's not going to drain more entropy or skew the distribution.  It's also easy to understand.

I'd leave it as it is.